# Sorting on a unknown property

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I’m building a small application, and in part of the UI you can sort some objects (persons). So when I call this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/addressbook/person/list?sort=name
```

all works nicely.

However, when I change the URL to the following, my application is throwing exceptions:

```
http://localhost:8080/addressbook/person/list?sort=thisisanunknowproperty
```

I get errors like:

```
Class 
org.hibernate.QueryException 
Message 
could not resolve property: thisisanunknownproperty of: persons.Person
```

This is really not what I want, of course. The application should just not sort, and not throw exceptions like this. But how do I prevent this behavior from happening?

Thing which come to mind is that I build something in which checks if the property is a member of the allowed properties to sort, but I'm wondering if there is anything out of the box for this which I missed?

Comment: You haven't missed anything that is 'out of the box'. What you are seeing is 'out of the box' behavior. In order to prevent this exception you have to write code to account for it.

Comment: without your controller code, it is hard to guess.  or is this generated? otherwise either use a whitelist for the properties you allow sorting on or use groovy hasProperty.

Comment: It's generated code indeed, sorry for not being clear about that.

Comment: You could introduce a `Filter` that analyses the request param `sort` and removes it when the property does not exist on the domain class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned via email, take a look at [Grails Command Objects](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.0/guide/theWebLayer.html#commandObjects) which are based around the [Spring Validation API](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html).

The hard and fast rule is never, ever blindly accept user input. In many frameworks, Grails included, this has exposed some nasty security holes.